# invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff

Tags: android, package

I am quite new to android development and tried to get familiar with popup menus.
So I followed this tutorial:

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/03/example-of-using-popupmenu.html

My minSdkVersion is 18, my target SdkVersion is 19, I transferred the apk to my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.3).
If I hit the button, the popup menu appears - so far no problem.

But if I look inside my LogCat the following message appears if I open the popup menu:

```
02-10 10:55:03.850: W/ResourceType(29714): Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0xffffffff
```

I tried to clean my project, I tried to delete the gen-folder and rebuilt the project but no luck.
I examined the `R.java` file but inside there is no resource with id `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Then I tried with the emulator, there this warning does not appear, so it seems it has to do with the Samsung Galaxy S4 phone itself.
So what to do now? Do I have to do anything (especially if I want to provide my app on Google Play Store) or can I leave it as it is and live with this warning?

Comment: is it causing any problems or crashes in the phone ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's not causing any crashes - it's ok. This can be caused as a result of using some android resources from `android.R. ...` or "@android: ..." which are not available on SG S4 as it has its own firmware while Android emulator uses "clean" Android.